# Why pyright with coc.nvim not working after opening another file?

Tags: neovim, language-server-protocol, pyright, coc.nvim

if I immediately open the file via nvim, then everything works, but if I first open, for example, the config, and after the python file, then pyright does not work

```lua
vim.cmd [[packadd packer.nvim]]
return require('packer').startup(function()
    use 'wbthomason/packer.nvim'
    use 'neovim/nvim-lspconfig'
    use 'williamboman/nvim-lsp-installer'
    use {
        'williamboman/mason.nvim',
        ensure_installed = {
            'pyright',
        },
    }
    use {'neoclide/coc.nvim', branch = 'release'}
    -- another plugins
end)
```

I still don't really understand what exactly is wrong here. in coc.nvim itself or in lspconfig

Answer (score 0):

The pyright plugin isn't properly configured with the Mason package installer
I assume you might have already tried `MasonInstall pyright` but still no luck!

Now, follow these steps

- Uninstall any autopairs plugin
- Uninstall friendly-snippets if you have it installed already
- Uninstall "pyright" from Mason using `MasonUninstall pyright` and remove it from "ensure_installed" table
- Now that everything is clean, use `CocInstall coc-pyright coc-pairs`
- Now you should have "pyright" running correctly

Incase, you want to use end to end properly configured neovim setup with modern looking IDE, you can clone my config [here](https://github.com/msp99000/nvim)